# Optimizing Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am currently trying to optimize my sieve further. I have to count primes between two numbers using the sieve of eratosthenes and I know that two numbers that need to work are 2000000000000 and 2000000100000. My current code gets a segmentation error due to taking too long to run. Any help in optimizing would be greatly appreciated:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double Sieve(long long a, long long b){

    //Create array of type bool
    bool *prime;
    prime = new bool[b];

    //Set all values in array to true
    for (long i = 0; i < b; i++){
        prime[i] = true;
    }


    long count = 0;

    //Runs through main Sieve algorithm
    for (long x = 2*2; x <= (b); x += 2 ){
        prime[x] = false;
    }
    for (long x = 3; x <= sqrt(b); x = 2*x ){
        if (prime[x] == true){
            for (long y = pow(x,2); y <= b; y += x){
                prime[y] = false;
            }
        }

    }

    //Loop to print out and count how many primes are present
    for (long x = a; x <= b; x++){
        if(prime[x] == true){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(){
    int a, b;
    cout << "Please enter two numbers separated by one space" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << Sieve(1,20) << endl;
    cout << Sieve(a,b) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Segmentation faults occur when you access memory you are not allowed to access and not due to running too long.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: You seem to be missing a function here: `for (long x = 2*2; x <= (b); x += 2 )`. This will cause a segmentation fault for `x == b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to allocate *way* too much memory, and the `new` is probably failing and throwing a [`std::bad_alloc` exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc). An uncaught exception may resemble a segmentation error if you're not paying attention.

To solve this you will need *two* arrays - one for your output range sized 100001, and one for determining the primes up to sqrt(b).

As noted by another answer, using `std::vector<bool>` will also cut your memory requirements by 8. Not enough to do away with requiring two arrays, but still a big help. Sometimes people will advise against `vector<bool>` because it has some oddities, but for this purpose it's perfect.

Comment: @manni66 of course you're right. I was thinking of `malloc` I guess. I can't remember the last time I tried a `new` that failed.

Comment: Regardless of the semantics of `new` vs `malloc`, this is on target, and should get you there for the exercise.  Meanwhile, you could play some further preprocessing tricks, like recognizing that all numbers other than 2 (which is not in your set), will not be prime, so only needing to allocate half of the elements.  For the small numbers, you could play further tricks, like recognizing all multiples of 3 (a fancy bit check, if not modulus), and get an additional 1/6 of your elements that you don't need store.  The cost, of course, is bookkeeping when printing out the results.

Comment: ^^ "all *[even]* numbers other than 2 will not be prime".

Comment: 110,000 primes will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running out of memory. Using an array of bool probably allocates 1byte for each entry, if you allowed to use `std::vector` then `std::vector<bool>` only uses a single bit.

Comment: Interesting, I just assumed it was due to running too long.  I have never used vector before but would it be as simple as changing my bool array to a vector bool array like you described?

Comment: @Knoep - that's a hardware problem ; - )

Comment: @MartinBeckett in the end it just underlines that your speculation as to why the OP was in trouble was very much spot on :)

Comment: @Knoep, I'm a physicist not a computer scientist. There is NEVER enough CPU/memory/storage/bandwidth !

Answer (score 0):

2000000000000 this is too big for an array. Rather use bitset. you can generate bigger primes in a much faster way. Declare the bitset in global scope this way it can hold 10^7. but then you can use the segmented sieve algorithm for making it work for 2000000000000. In this case sqrt(2000000000000) = 1414213.something thats why you have to generate all prime number between 2 and 1414214. And then use the segmented sieve algorithm

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define bitset_range 1414214
typedef long long int lli;
typedef long int li;
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
void printer(T a) {
    cout << a << endl;
}
vector<li> stock_prime;
bitset<bitset_range + 1> numbers;
int main() {
    lli start, stop;
    //normal seieve
    numbers.set();
    numbers.reset(0);
    numbers.reset(1);
    for (li i = 2; i <= bitset_range; i++) {
        if (numbers.test(i)) {
            for (li j = i * i; j <= bitset_range; j+= i) {
                numbers.reset(j);
            }
            stock_prime.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    //for_each(stock_prime.begin(), stock_prime.end(), printer<int>);
    cout << "Size: " << stock_prime.size() << endl;

    //now use segmented seive algorithm here remember to use bitset rather than bool array



    return 0;
}
```